# Using Python regex to identify retweeters from tweets with Chinese characters

Tags: python, regex, weibo

Given a tweet of Sina Weibo:

```
  tweet = "//@lilei: dd //@Bob: cc//@Girl: dd//@魏武: 利益所致 自然念念不忘// @诺什: 吸引优质  客户，摆脱屌丝男！！！//@MarkGreene: 转发微博"
```

Note that there is a space between // and @诺什.

I want to get a list of retweeters, like this:

```
  result = ['lilei', 'Bob', 'Girl', '魏武', 'MarkGreene']
```

I have been thinking about using the following script:

```
RTpattern = r'''//?@(\w+)'''
rt = re.findall(RTpattern, tweet)
```

However, I failed in getting the Chinese word '魏武'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`re.UNICODE`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.UNICODE) flag:

```
re.UNICODE
Make \w, \W, \b, \B, \d, \D, \s and \S dependent on the Unicode character 
properties database.
```

---

```
tweet = u"//@lilei: dd //@Bob: cc//@Girl: dd//@魏武: 利益所致 自然念念不忘// @诺什: 吸引优质  客户，摆脱屌丝男！！！//@MarkGreene: 转发微博"
RTpattern = r'''//?@(\w+)'''
for word in re.findall(RTpattern, tweet, re.UNICODE):
    print word

# lilei
# Bob
# Girl
# 魏武
# MarkGreene
```

Comment: Thank you. I get ['lilei', 'Boy', 'Girl', '\xe9', 'MarkGreene'], rather than ['lilei', 'Bob', 'Girl', '魏武', 'MarkGreene']

Comment: You have to make the tweet a `unicode` string (note the `u`). To do that just add `tweet = tweet.decode('utf-8')`